# How to make a trapezoid with Geometry Nodes in Blender 3.0

Tags: 3d, blender

How can i make a trapezoid with thick walls (just like Solidify Modifier does) using only Geometry Nodes in Blender 3.0?
[Exapmle 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjoBV.png)
[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7q2U.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use Quadrilateral node in Curve Primitive select Trapezoid.
2. Use "Curve to Mesh" with straight "Curve Line" to extrude.
3. Connect with Convex Hull to convert curve to mesh.
4. Use Transform node to shrink and connect with Mesh Boolean select Difference to subtract.

This is concept set up:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybeS2.png]

Blender Document: [Quadrilateral Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/pt/3.0/modeling/geometry_nodes/curve_primitives/quadrilateral.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).